# Access the same running code from a Windows Service and a console application?

Tags: c#, .net, architecture, windows-services, .net-2.0

I have an application that is built as a Windows Service and a c# library assembly (.dll.) In order to manage and maintain this service, I'd like to add the ability to run a command-line application that tells the last time the service archived files, the next time it's scheduled to do so, the status of the last run, and the location of a file created by the service.

What's the best architecture for writing a service and library that can share data with another application? I'm using .net 2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way that inter-process communication happens in .net is through remoting (even if both processes are on the same machine).  Other responses have suggested alternatives to inter-process communication which would not require remoting.

Answer (score 2):

The best architecture is probably to make your service be a "server" that can report on it's status (and whatever information you want). Using WCF for this like ocdecio suggested would make it pretty simple.

Answer (score 1):

I use WCF for that and create a contract definition for the commands/events I want to support.

Comment: Excellent answer. I should have mentioned I'm using VS .net2.0, though.

Answer (score 1):

Options that spring to mind that I've applied in the past:

- Save the information to a database
  (if you have one to hand)
- Implement a
  "status monitor" type thread on the
  service that the client can connect
  to and query via TCP/IP etc.

Comment: So why vote this down -- all approaches that could work. Sheesh. By all means vote an answer down if it's wrong, and explain why in a comment; but with no justification it just hurts the greater knowledge.

Comment: It may have been a ninja downvote. It looks like everyone who answered this question got one. It certainly wasn't from me.

Comment: My previous company had a similar architecture for a service / UI application.  Worked great.

Answer (score 1):

A fairly simple approach is to store that information in either a local config / text file which both apps have access to.  Or even to place it in a registry key.

Answer (score 1):

+1 for just having the service provide that (and any other data) when it is queried (simple tcp, RPC, web service, or whatever)

I'd make it pretty generic - like

QueryInfo(some identifier)
with a response as some string and a return value or other indicator that the service does not know what you are talking about, cannot get the info, or give back the info